# Don't show button on product view page by custom module

Tags: magento

I want to show button on product view page by custom module. For this i have write below code:-

**app/etc/modules/Local_Productview**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Local_Productview>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
     </Local_Productview>
   </modules>
</config>
```

**Local/Productview/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Local_Productview>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Local_Productview>
 </modules>
 <global>
    <helpers>
        <productview>
            <class>Local_Productview_Helper</class>
        </productview>
    </helpers>
 </global>
 <frontend>
     <layout>
     <updates>
             <productview>
                 <file>productview.xml</file>
             </productview>
         </updates>
     </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

**Local/Productview/Helper/Data.php**

```
class Vivacity_Productview_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**frontend/default/default/layout/productview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
<catalog_product_view translate="label">    
     <reference name="product.info.extrahint" >
        <block type="core/template"  name="stock">
             <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>productview/productview.phtml</template>
             </action> 
        </block>
     </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**frontend/default/default/template/productview/productview.phtml**

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

Comment: When something strange happens with layout, I put <remove name="header" /> inside handle, reference. This way you can check if your layout works, if header really removed

Comment: Not working. i am using magento 1.9 version.

Comment: What doesn't work? Show what are you trying to do. Magento version doesn't matter. Maybe remove translate="label" from your handle. Replace your handle name with default

Comment: I am write a custom module to put button on product view page.

Comment: Not working i have removed and changed the translate label

Comment: if header doesn't disappear - it means that your layout xml doesn't work. Did you refresh cache (or better disable) ?

Comment: I have disable cache. but on working

Comment: Try to create module using custom module creator. Maybe you did a small mistake somewhere and you can spend a lot of time to debug it.

Comment: What is custom module create? Will you please send me url ?

Comment: http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: Got the error i need to put the file in base folder not in default folder. cheers. Can you please let me know why this happen if i put file in frontend/default why this is not showing.

Comment: It could happened because instead of default theme you used some another

Comment: glad to hear that everything is working

Answer (score 0):

- As solution - better put your custom layouts and templates in
  base/default folder.
- If you have some problems with layout - put inside your handle or reference `<remove name="header" />`
- Try to replace your handle with `<default>` handle
- If your new created module doesn't work and you spent a lot of time on bugfix - try to create same module (or part of it) using automatic module creator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom theme you can also add your layout changes to a local.xml file.

This file should be under `package/theme/layout/local.xml`

Then you can add you xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>    
         <reference name="product.info.extrahint" >
            <block type="core/template" name="stock" template="productview/productview.phtml" />
         </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```